# Where could this oil leak originate on this Mazda 6?

Tags: oil-leak, mazda-6

2007 Mazda 6 3.0L V6, driven daily, has been dripping a few drops of oil per day from this ... what the heck is this bent piece of metal that looks like it actually has a drip spout?  And where is the leak likely to be originating and what are recommended diagnostics or repairs?

[image: Mazda 6 Undercarriage]

[image: Oil leak point]

[image: Oil leak point detail]

Comment: Check carefully because the source can be higher up - even a rocker cover gasket can be the real cause. Check thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

That looks to be where the transmission bellhousing meets the engine block. If that's the spot, the leak is most likely the rear main seal. This is where the engine crankshaft comes out of the engine and the place where the flexplate (assuming an automatic transmission) connects to it. There is a seal which circles the crankshaft. A leak where you're showing it is usually caused from this seal leaking.

This is not an easy fix, because one has to remove the engine/tranny from the car (most front wheel drive cars requires this), then split the tranny and engine, remove the parts, replace the seal, then put it all together again. A lot of work for a $20 seal.

Comment: Many fwd cars can have the transmission removed without removing the engine and to achieve this sometimes the subframe needs to be dropped a small amount but not in all cases.

Comment: Sounds likely ... which on a car this old may not justify the trouble.  Are there any "hack" fixes, if for nothing else than to keep the oil from staining parking spots?  (I won't say "duct tape" because I assume that any external adhesive seal would fail because half of what it would have to cover rotates?)

Comment: @feetwet - Other than putting [Pigmat](https://www.newpig.com/absorbent-mats/c/100) under the vehicle where it drips, no, not a single hack fix I can think of.

Comment: Or a torque converter seal

Comment: @Moab - Not if it's engine oil ...

Comment: Trans fluid looks like engine oil if its burnt.

Comment: @Moab – yeah I checked the transmission fluid and it's in good condition, so I ruled that out as being the source of this drip.

Comment: Local mechanic confirmed it's leaking from the crankshaft seal.  Not worth a proper repair given the present value of the car.  He recommended taking a shot with a quart of Lucas Engine Oil Stop Leak, saying there's a chance that will restore some pliability to the seals and reduce the leak rate.